# PHP loading issues

Tags: php

Hello i came across a problem  when im using require_once/include and you refresh the page the latest loaded content is flashing for a sec befor it finish loading,
theres no image involved aswell.

heres screenshot from loading 
http://prntscr.com/823189

and from after loading 
http://prntscr.com/8231dj

Index file

```
    /* Url get request */
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
}

/* ID get request */
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}


require_once __DIR__ . '/server.php';
```

server file

```
/* load options */
require_once __DIR__ . '/option.php';


/* load autoloader */
require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap/autoload.php';


/* Load view */
require_once __DIR__ . '/resource/view/index.php';
```

View index

```
/* Load Header partial */
require_once '/resource/view/template/Header.php';

its class to include pages
/* Load Routing */
require_once ('/app/http/route.php');

/* Load Footer partial */
require_once '/resource/view/template/Footer.php';
```

autoloader

```
/* starting session */
session_start();


/* load db config file */
require_once '/config/config.php';

/* require login class */
require_once ('/bootstrap/Login.php');

    /* User login/register/reset */
    $login = new Login($objConn,$_POST,$url,$id);
    $login->Dbconnection();
    $role = $login->Role();


    just include all classes
    /* load vendor autoloader */
    require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging what so ever?  As from an initial glimpse you haven't & it's likely your problem doesn't lie completely in what you've provided.. do some debugging and get back to us.

Comment: what do you mean flashing, generally this is a javascript or browser caching issue not a severside issue.  It's just not how it works severside. Not to mention this is a syntax error as posted `just include all classes`

Comment: the just include all classes were just a comment i made its not actualy in the code. and also theres no javascript involved its doing it with just the php code alone, and also artisiticPhoenix i mean like when you load the page its only bottom of the site that was latest included on the page so example the Footer include is the only part of the site flashing like its not loaded yet

Comment: Just hit F12 and see what resources takes so long to load. Unless, you are flushing the output buffer, it will load as a whole not partially(assuming javascript and css are not loading anything from somewhere).

Comment: hmm it seem it issues is if theres any javascript involved or the page becomes too long even if the page require almost no effort to load and the loading resource seem normal takes less then 80 ms to load the entire page.

Comment: hmm seem the issue was the wamp server.

Comment: If you think it's something other people might benefit from, feel free to add an answer.